# Oracle sql: Drop table column shows error: invalid identifier?

Tags: oracle, multiple-columns, ddl, alter-table

I get this error when I am trying to drop multiple column in one statement:-

```
    ALTER TABLE "RLX_ROLES" DROP COLUMN ("test","test_2");
```

But it works if I drop them one by one:-

```
    ALTER TABLE "RLX_ROLES" DROP COLUMN "test";
    ALTER TABLE "RLX_ROLES" DROP COLUMN "test_2";
```

Why so? Is my syntax not correct?

Edit:-
I have also tried:-

```
    ALTER TABLE RLX_ROLES DROP (test,test_2);
```

and

```
    ALTER TABLE RLX_ROLES DROP COLUMN (test,test_2);
```

UPDATE:-

Apparently, I spelled one of the column names wrong, sorry about it.

Comment: Show the error just like I have shown a demo. Copy paste your session. And describe your table using `DESC`.

Comment: As others have mentioned, *alter table <table_name> drop (<column1>, <column2>);* should work. If you still get an error, please add the complete DDL for your table to the question - you might have case-sensitive column names, in which case you'll have to use double quotes and the *exact* spelling in your DROP statement.

Comment: Error starting at line 3 in command:
ALTER TABLE RLX_ROLES DROP(test_2,test_3,test_1)
Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-00904: "TEST_1": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
*Cause:    
*Action:

Comment: ok, there was a mispelling, sorry!

Comment: That's why I asked you to *show the error just like I have shown a demo. Copy paste your session. And describe your table using `DESC`*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use the following statement to drop more than one columns:

```
alter table table_name drop (col_name1, col_name2);
```

Then you have to delete the "column"  keyword in your statement.

Comment: I had already tried that, still get error

Comment: Have you tried without the quotes? Just put the table names

Answer (score 1):

> Drop table column shows error: invalid identifier?
>
> ALTER TABLE "RLX_ROLES" DROP COLUMN ("test","test_2");

There are two things incorrect in the alter statement you are using.

1. **COLUMN** keyword is not required for dropping multiple columns.
2. You don't need **double quotation marks**.

Using double-quotes:

```
SQL> ALTER TABLE t DROP ("b", "c");
ALTER TABLE t DROP ("b", "c")
                         *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00904: "c": invalid identifier


SQL>
```

So, remove the column keyword and the double-quotation marks.

It is all documented about [Removing Columns from Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/tables006.htm#ADMIN11663).

> Removing Columns from Tables
>
> When you issue an ALTER TABLE...DROP COLUMN statement, the column
>   descriptor and the data associated with the target column are removed
>   from each row in the table. You can drop multiple columns with one
>   statement.

Dropping a **single column**:

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE t(
  2  A NUMBER,
  3  b NUMBER,
  4  c NUMBER
  5  );

Table created.

SQL>
SQL> ALTER TABLE t DROP column c;

Table altered.
```

Dropping **multiple columns**:

```
SQL> drop table t purge;

Table dropped.

SQL> CREATE TABLE t(
  2  a NUMBER,
  3  b NUMBER,
  4  c NUMBER
  5  );

Table created.

SQL>
SQL> ALTER TABLE t DROP (b, c);

Table altered.

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove the double quotes. they are not needed and you have to remove the keyword `column` if you would like to drop more than one column.

```
ALTER TABLE RLX_ROLES DROP (test,test_2);
```

See [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_3001.htm#SQLRF01001) for more information about `alter` syntax.

Comment: I had already tried that, still get error

Comment: @SohamBanerjee same error?

Answer (score 0):

Presumably you have inadvertently created your table with case-sensitive column names (by using double quotes for them). If that's the case, you'll have to use double quotes and the exact spelling in your `DROP` statement:

```
create table RLX_ROLES("test" number, "Test_2" number, test3 number);

alter table RLX_ROLES drop ("Test_2","test");
```

To generate a SQL statement for dropping all the columns with the correct spelling, you can use this statement (please note that running this statement unchanged will raise an error because you cannot drop all the columns in a table):

```
select 'alter table ' || table_name ||
  ' drop (' || 
  listagg('"' || utc.column_name || '"', ',') within group (order by utc.column_name) ||
  ');'
from user_tab_cols utc
where table_name = 'RLX_ROLES'
group by table_name;
```

This queries the `user_tab_cols` dictionary view to get all column names for the RLX_ROLES table and uses the `LISTAGG` aggregation function to concatenate them.